# If a triangle is contained in an algebraic variety, is its span contained too?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ be an irreducible projective variety. Let us suppose that there exist three distinct points $x,y,z\in X$ such that 
$$
\langle x,y\rangle\subset X,
$$
$$
\langle x,z\rangle\subset X,
$$
$$
\langle y,z\rangle\subset X.
$$
Is it true that the plane generated by $x,y,z$ is contained in $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A cubic surface in $\mathbb P^3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Please, add details. I don't find this counterexample convincing.

Comment: There are triangles on the cubic surface, formed by some triples of the 27 lines. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_surface#27_lines_on_a_cubic_surface for some references to the 27 lines story.

Comment: @LevBorisov Is there any difference if any secant line to $X$ either lies on $X$ or intersects $X$ at exactly two points?

Comment: I am confused by your question. In my example $X$ is a cubic. Every line that does not lie in $X$ completely, would intersect it in three points, counted with multiplicity, provided the base field is algebraically closed.